# Magento flat category not working

Tags: magento, magento-1.8

I have enable flat category from magento admin panel **system->catalog->catolog->frontend** set **Use Flat Catalog Category** to "yes" after that I **re indexed Category Flat Data** . But after that images of category are not visible in frontend. please tell me if I am doing anything wrong.

Comment: Are you using some custom code to get the category image? If yes please post here with your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you check magento logs generated at the following location

> root_folder/var/log

I faced the same issue previously but after clearing cache .
It did the job.

Comment: I have also Tried it but showing main categories under sub categories which is wrong please give another suggestion